# Data validation clear value

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have a data validation list (drop down menu) in Cell B43 and my intention is to clear the date from an adjacent cell B44, every time the list value changes value.

I thought I could do it with the VBA below but nothing happens

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_agreement(ByVal target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(target, Range("b43")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("b44").ClearContents
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Change `agreement` to `Change`?

Comment: That simple :| , thank you